# Java Reactor: How to produce Flux from stdin?

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I would like to asynchronously read messages produced by user from stdin.
Something like:

```
Flux.from(stdinPublisher()) 
    .subscribe(msg -> System.out.println("Received: " + msg));
```

So how to implement such stdin publisher here?

Comment: the source code of `stdinPublisher` method?

Comment: Yes. I would like to subscribe and receive messages created by user. It could be `stdinPublisher` method implementation or some another approach, no matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was easy. Sorry for disturb :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class StdinProducerExample implements ApplicationRunner {

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    Flux
        .create(sink -> {
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            sink.next(scanner.nextLine());
          }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newSingle("stdin publisher"))
        .subscribe(m -> log.info("User message: {}", m));
    log.info("Started listening stdin");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of producing data with Reactor are [`Processors`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_safely_produce_from_multiple_threads_by_using_the_sink_facade).

> `FluxProcessor` sinks safely gate multi-threaded producers and can be
>   used by applications that generate data from multiple threads
>   concurrently. For example, you can create a thread-safe serialized
>   sink for `UnicastProcessor`. Multiple producer threads may
>   concurrently generate data on the following serialized sink:

```
public class FluxProcessorSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    FluxProcessor<String, String> processor = UnicastProcessor.<String>create().serialize();
    FluxSink<String> sink = processor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);

    // Print input to STDOUT
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
        .execute(() -> processor
            .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .map(str -> "1>> " + str)
            .subscribe(System.out::println));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      sink.next(scanner.nextLine());
    }
  }
}
```

A `UnicastProcessor` can deal with backpressure by using an internal buffer. The trade-off is that it can have at most one `Subscriber`. If you push any amount of data through it while its Subscriber has not yet requested data, it buffers all of the data.

Other [`FluxProcessor` implementations](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processor-overview) are:

- `DirectProcessor` - Can dispatch signals to zero or more
  `Subscribers`. It has the limitation of not handling backpressure
- `EmitterProcessor` - Can emit to several subscribers while honoring
  backpressure for each of its subscribers. When it has no subscriber,
  it can still accept a few data pushes up to a configurable
  `bufferSize`.